# Can this silver-colored skillet be put and used in ovens for baking?

Tags: equipment, oven

My grandparents own this silver-colored skillet. QUEENSENSE SENSHIN is the only printed on it, at the bottom.

[image]

To save money and space, they desire to dual-purpose this skillet not only for cooking on stove-top, but also baking inside oven. But how can they deduce if they can safely insert this skillet into the oven for baking, like the pictures below?

Comment: Similar to your other question - the picture of the real pan is quite useful. Random pictures of pans being put into ovens don't contribute to the question, so I removed them.

Answer (score 3):

If the skillet is entirely made out of metal, then yes, you can use this in the oven. If there are any non-metal parts or coatings, it depends on what those are. Without manufacturer information about oven safety, in the latter case I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 0):

The current [Queen Sense](https://www.my-rialto.com/queensense/index.htm) catalog contains nothing similar to your pan. It looks like they've gone the nonstick route, with plastic handles. Their care instructions specifically say, not to use them in ovens. But your pan looks all metal, so as LSchoon says, it should be OK. The link I supplied includes a "contact us" button, if you want to know for sure.